# Laravel eloquent relationship how to use whereIn ids([1,2,3]) as foreign key in model

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
 public function subModel() {
        return $this->hasMany(subModel::class,'array of ids like [1,2]','id');
    }
```

I want to match an array of IDs using a relationship and get multiple data.

so how can I get data from the array inside the array?

Comment: Is this something that you would need on a relationshiop everytime?

Comment: yes, usually we pass a single foreign key id instead of a single we should pass array of key ids , How can I pass it?

Comment: Ok, do you have foreign keys IDs in a variable or is it static? Also, these IDs are of the Model class or subModel class?

Comment: foreign key IDs are variable not static and inside mode we are calling function with hasMany relastionships